# Is it possible to create a simple parser and create a javascript file and then call that file with that parser?

Tags: javascript, pegjs

I am trying to create a parser, a file. I am trying to use this file created to be parsed by the parser. The steps are:

1. Add pegjs with
2. Create an parser with **var parserFile**
3. Create file with **var makeFile**
4. Add contentFile,  nameFile with  **var contentFile, nameFile** and **here: var makeFile**
5. Use parser in **var makeFile** with **var parserFile**

```
// @author  dikafon 
// @license runFile, license: Open source, 05-10-2019
// @readme  Include pegs.js and build parser, generate file, include grammar in file, download, run script.rF ( template, output )

var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var fileScript = document.createElement('script');
fileScript.type = 'text/javascript';
fileScript.src = 'https://pegjs.org/vendor/pegjs/peg.js';
head.appendChild(fileScript);


var runFile = (function () {

  // make, Grammar 
  var parserFile;

  parserFile = PEG.buildParser(
  "start\n"+
  "= comment def runFile msgbox rules_list\n"+
  "comment = COMSTART (not_com/comment)* COMSTOP\n"+
  "not_com = (!COMSTOP !COMSTART.)\n"+
  "COMSTART='.'\n"+
  "COMSTOP='.'\n"+
  "def\n"+
  "= def:'runFile'? __ { return runFile; }\n"+
  "runFile\n"+
  "= runFile:('bat'/'cmd'/'hta'/'vbs'/'rF') _ { return runFile;}\n"+  
  "msgbox\n"+
  "= msgbox:('runFile')_ { return msgbox;}\n"+
  "rules_list\n"+
  "= '(' _ exp:[a-zA-Z]+ _ ')' { return [ exp.join('') ]; }\n"+
  "_  = [ \t\r\n]*\n"+
  "__ = [ \t\r\n]"
   );

     // make, File 
     var makeFile = document.createElement("a");
     document.body.appendChild(a);
     makeFile.style = "display: none";

     // grammar how 'content, File' && 'name, File'
     return function (contentFile, nameFile) {

     // setting, file 
         var define = file, 
               blob = new Blob([text], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"}), 
                url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

             makeFile.href = url;
             makeFile.download = nameFile;
             makeFile.click();
             window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);

     };

 }());

// content, file

var file = (function () {

  var contentFile, nameFile, finishFile;
  contentFile = (". runFile, license: Open source, 05-10-2019. \n"+ "def 
  runFile(rF) \n"+"msgbox('runFile');"+"\n");

  finishFile = runFile(contentFile , nameFile); 
  nameFile = "script.rF";

})(); 


// call, file & grammar 
// show

     console.log(

     ". runFile, license: Open source, 05-10-2019. \n"+ 
     "def runFile(rF) \n"+
     "msgbox('runFile');"+
     "\n"

     );

     // generate, file and download, run script ( contentFile, nameFile ) 
     // build parser, parser.parse 
     console.log((parser.parse(runFile(file))));
```

- > Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'
- > Line 1, column 1: Expected "." but "2" found.

Comment: You've got a stray trailing `+` in the initialization of `contentFile`.

Comment: `var contentFile = parser.parse(contentFile, nameFile);` that doesn't look right - since you're defining `contentFile` here, passing it as an argument to the function that defines it is wrong

Comment: `var file = (function() {` appears to be the start of an IIFE, however the function is incomplete and doesn't return anything, so *file* is undefined. It's unclear to me what `runFile(file)` does. *runFile* accepts two arguments, but is called with only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until syntax errors are fixed, runtime errors should probably be ignored. There is a syntax error here:

```
var file = (function () {  // <== opening bracket signals the possible start of an IIFE
  ...
}  // <== closing bracket ")" expected

// call, file & grammar 
// show
console.log( ...
```

Either the opening "(" or the missing closing ")" are syntax errors. The function on the right hand side of the assignment to *file* doesn't have a return statement, so I guess that it's the opening "(" that is the typo and an IIFE is not intended.

The first argument passed to *runFile*, i.e. *contentFile*, isn't used in the function.

The *runFile* function doesn't have a return statement so returns *undefined*. Assigning the result to *finishFile* seems pointless.

Once the syntax errors are fixed, there will be runtime errors.